# Checking a series of dictionaries for a common key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a series of dictionaries in python that were generated from a control file.  The control file was just a list of hostnames that we're used to parse a webpage for data.  If the hostname was listed in the url, then I would store the full line of data in a dictionary based on the hostname being the key, and the line being the value.  After creating the various dictionaries, I get the following output from them.

```
audit_dicts = {
   "us_osdata":us_osdata, 
   "us_weblogic":us_weblogic, 
   "us_tomcat":us_tomcat
   blah
   blah
   }
for key in audit_dicts:
    print "Length of the %s dictionary is %d lines." % (key, len(audit_dicts[key]))
```

Output:

```
Total number of hosts in the control file: 4376
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The length of the us_mq dictionary is 266 lines.
The length of the us_oracle dictionary is 198 lines.
The length of the uk_mq dictionary is 59 lines.
The length of the us_osdata dictionary is 765 lines.
The length of the us_websphere_ut dictionary is 137 lines.
The length of the uk_websphere dictionary is 33 lines.
The length of the uk_osdata dictionary is 228 lines.
The length of the uk_oracle dictionary is 41 lines.
The length of the us_weblogic dictionary is 144 lines.
The length of the us_jboss dictionary is 59 lines.
The length of the us_sunweb dictionary is 80 lines.
The length of the us_websphere dictionary is 165 lines.
The length of the us_ihs dictionary is 147 lines.
The length of the us_tcserver dictionary is 0 lines.
The length of the uk_weblogic dictionary is 5 lines.
The length of the us_tomcat dictionary is 236 lines.
```

---

I would like to cycle through the control file for each hostname and print all data associated with that hostname stored in the dictionaries in audit_dicts, on a single line.

pseudo code """

```
for x in control:
        combine = {}
        if x in ** any ** of the audit_dicts[key]
            append values aka lines from all dicts  to combined dictionary
        else
            append x as the key and value.
```

Sorry, this may be a silly question, as I'm completely new to programming.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to what you want the end output to look like. Can you show me what you want the dict to look like after the parsing? The Pseudocode is confusing me

Comment: The various dictionaries will have a line of data that may or may not match the key.  I would like to cycle through the control file one last time, verify if the host in the control file matches any keys in the various dictionaries.  Any matches would append the data to a single row/line, otherwise it just prints a hostname (control file name).  So, it can have a single hostname if no match to the dictionaries, or matches to single or multiple dictionaries.  IN which case it just appends to the end of the same row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could combine them beforehand:

```
from collections import defaultdict

combined = defaultdict(list)

for d in dicts:
    for key, value in d.items():
        combined[key].append(value)
```

Now, `combined` contains a list of values from each of those dictionaries.